# Pandas will not import

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, importerror

When I import pandas I keep getting the error `ImportError: Can't determine version for bottleneck` in jupyter notebook. I have tried the other stack overflow link with the same question and uninstalling and then reinstalling bottle neck and this does not work. So I am asking the same question hoping someone has a different answer.

Comment: did you try `conda install Bottleneck`

Comment: also see [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29181)

Comment: Thank you for responding, Yes i have tried conda install Bottleneck, but I receive the same error. And I have already seen that GitHub link, and tried everything on that page but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment, e.g. conda env?

Comment: No I am in the base enviorment, should I be using a virtual one? If so what python should I use?